# Is there any reference treating explicitly Lie-Rinehart pairs over non-commutative base algebras?

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, lie-algebroids

Wondering around in the literature, any reference to Lie-Rinehart algebras define them as pairs $(A,L)$ where $A$ is a *commutative* algebra over some field $\Bbbk$ (or even commutative ring) and $L$ is a Lie algebra satisfying certain additional properties.

However, in the nlab page about [Lie-Rinehart pairs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie-Rinehart+pair) seems to be more or less explicitly written that commutativity of $A$ is *not* necessary. Namely, therein a *Lie-Rinehart pair* is defined as a couple $(A,L)$ where

- $A$ is a non-commutative associative and unital algebra
- $L$ is a Lie algebra
- $L$ acts on $A$ by $\Bbbk$-linear derivations (i.e. we have a Lie algebra map $\omega:L \to \mathsf{Der}_{\Bbbk}(A)$)
- $A$ acts on $L$ by $\Bbbk$-linear endomorphisms (i.e. we have an algebra map $A \to \mathsf{End}_{\Bbbk}(L)$) such that $$[X,aY] = \omega(X)(a)Y + a [X,Y]$$ for all $X,Y \in L$ and $a \in A$.

In light of this, I am a bit surprised of not finding papers in non-commutative geometry treating this slightly more general "non-commutative analogue" of Lie-Rinehart algebras. Is there anybody aware of some reference doing it? Maybe under a different name than "Lie-Rinehart algebras" or "Lie-Rinehart pairs"?

Answer (score 2):

A non-commutative version of a Lie-Rinehart algebra was introduced by
Michel Van den Bergh in *Non-commutative quasi-Hamiltonian spaces in Poisson geometry in mathematics and physics*, Volume 450 of Contemp. Math., pages 273–299. Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2008.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out Van den Bergh's paper. However, and pardon my layman comment, I had a quick look at it and I am experiencing some difficulties in finding the non-commutative version of a Lie-Rinehart algebra you are referring to. Are you speaking about *double Lie algebroids*, by chance?

Comment: Exactly. I refer to Johan Leray who says in [Shifted Double Lie-Rinehart Algebra](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01710885/document) on page $3$: "we study a particular type of double Poisson algebras called linear double Poisson algebras. They correspond to double Lie-Rinehart algebras (called double Lie algebroids by Van den Bergh in [VdB08a, Sect. 3.2]), which are the noncommutative version of Lie-Rinehart algebras".

Comment: Many thanks! That sounds great, but alas not exactly what I was looking for. For the moment, I am still concerned with the much easier case in which we have a Lie algebra acting on a non-commutative algebra by derivations and the same algebra acting on the Lie algebra by endomorphisms satisfying a kind of Leibniz rule. I will amend the question to clarify it.

Comment: It would be useful to have a motivation for why we want to consider this generalised type of algebra. For double Lie algebroids there is a lot of motivation.

Comment: At the point in which I am, my motivation is exactly "could it be interesting to consider this type of algebras?" (i.e., mainly curiosity). I always worked with the classical definition of LR-algebras, but a few days ago I run into the definition of LR-pair in ncatlab, which sounded to me like "non-commutative Lie algebroid" in the spirit of "naive non-commutative geometry". As a consequence, I started to look around to see where this definition of LR-pair was coming from and what has already been said in this direction, but I didn't find anything. So, I considered asking here.